# Mathematical notation programming looping for array element assignment, no summation or product

Tags: math, notation

I am looking for the appropriate mathematical notation that will represent this code.

```
for(X = 0; X < ACA_Bin.size; X++) {
   ACA_CORRECTION[X] = ACA_Bin[X] + ACA_OFFSET
}
```

This is not a summation or product that would require a Sigma Notation

So is there an assignment Notation?

Comment: Might be more appropriate on math.stackexchange.com since the question is about a mathematical representation, not a programming one.

Comment: Thanks, I'll post over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write ACA_Correction and ACA_Bin as vectors, say **x** and **y**:

**x** = (x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>N</sub>)

**y** = (y<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>, ..., y<sub>N</sub>)

where x<sub>i</sub> is the ith element of x and y<sub>i</sub> is the ith element of y.

The loop could be represented as:

**x** = **y** + offset

where *offset* is ACA_OFFSET in your code.

You can think of **x** and **y** as collections of elements. '**x** = **y** + offset' is simply saying '**x** is the result of adding offset to every element in **y**'. This is equivalent to your loop.

You can find more about vector notation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_notation).

Comment: Thanks, is this notation understood as a loop since the subscript is a variable?  I thought it require more description.

Comment: I've added a bit more description. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: Excellent,  I think I got it. Thanks for the answer. I click 1 up, but I don't have enough Rep Points.